# New Phoenix project on Ubuntu getting [error] backend port not found: :inotifywait

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I created a new phoenix project and when I run mix phoenix.server, I get

[error] backend port not found: :inotifywait

in red in my console. This looks menacing and, since I haven't really done anything yet, seems like the type of thing that should work.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: On linux: `apt-get install inotify-tools`.

Answer (score 13):

You need to add the `inotify` backend. Please see the readme here and you should be quickly on your way:
https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_live_reload#backends